# Getting a column of data from a different table MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I'm not very competent with MySQL joins so I would appreciate some help.

I have two tables. Lets call them `X` and `Y`.

`X` is the main table, however I want to get one column of data from table `Y` where the `site_id` in table `X` corresponds to the `site_id` in table `Y`.

Example scheme for table `X`: `id, site_id, notes`

Example scheme for table `Y`: `id, site_id, name`

I would like to then create a query to have `id, site_id, notes, name` where `name` corresponds to the `site_id`

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    X.id, 
    X.site_id, 
    X.notes, 
    Y.name
FROM
    X
    LEFT JOIN Y ON X.site_id = Y.site_id
```